# testing return status for emalloc

Tags: c, php-extension

I am writing a couple of PHP extensions as a personal project.  (I used to use C professionally a few decades ago for developing realtime and process control applications, so I am a bit paranoid about always checking memory allocator returns and ensuring that error paths don't leak memory.  But then came the world of C++ and exception handlers.)  Now I have a simple Q:

Do I or don't I need to do a NULL-check on `buf` after:

```
buf = emalloc(rec->len);
```

Normally on a FLOSS project, I would just use the existing source as a template to answer this sort of Q, but the PHP extensions are inconsistent.  Statically analysing the complex C preprocessed code is impractical, and I can only easily test my own LAMP stack.  Basicially as far as I can see emalloc code does invoke zend error routines on heap exhaustion, but the code then continues and returns 0.  Some extension code cases do check for NULL return, yet you also find examples such as in `PHPAPI void php_basename()` in `ext/standard/string.c` such as:

```
if (p_ret) {
    ret = emalloc(len + 1);
    memcpy(ret, comp, len);
    ret[len] = '\0';
    *p_ret = ret;
}
```

which will generate a hard memory exception if emalloc does return rather than throwing a zend exception.

If anyone knows the official PHP developer answer, I'd be grateful for this.  Thanks.

Comment: What does the documentation for that `emalloc` function say about this?

Comment: You can try to create such a situation by trying to allocate a large number of memory: `emalloc(99999999999)` (add more 9s if necessary).

Comment: @Mat, I missed the one sentence that **unwind** pointed out.  My experience of FLOSS projects (I've only contributed to 4) is that such documentation is minimal or none-existent. The developers don't bother, and you are expected to reengineer this from code-inspection. [One page](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.memory.management.php) covering the entire basic MM system is better than average.

Comment: @Lekensteyn, thanks, but as I pointed out in my Q I can only do this test on my LAMP stack.  The code generated for Win32 or ARM is different and the fact that emalloc fails on Intel/LAMP doesn't mean that it consistently fails on all build variants.

Comment: @TerryE: that's a really poor excuse for not reading what documentation is available. Docs are just like everything else, they'll exist if someone bothered writing them, and they'll be good if people volunteer time to maintain them. If you don't even try to read them (let alone provide feedback to improve them), they'll wont get better.

Comment: @Mat, have a look at PHP official documentation for [Creating variables and setting values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.variables.creating.php) to see what I mean :)

Comment: @Mat it's not a poor excuse: it's being human missing footnote in one of the few pages that do exist. IMO, very rarely do you need to ask Qs as the data is easily searchable.  I've answered ~300 Qs here and asked 2.  I don't do this lightly. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.memory.management.php) clearly states:

> Note: Unlike their C standard library's counterparts the Zend Engine's memory management functions won't return NULL in case of an problem while allocating the requested memory but bail out and terminate the current request.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.  I missed this note in this one-pager.  What threw me off is that the actually some e* routines contain continuation paths ending in `return 0;` or `return NULL;`  Why do this if the engine raises a memory exhaustion error?